# how to place image inside another image on buttonclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a class **boxright** with backgrround image of `cave`

i have a button which on onclick it points to function `ontop()` which reset the backgroundimage of boxright to an image `cheetah`

i want the cheetah to appear on top the cave, ie on **buttonclick i want the cheeteh to appear inside the cave**

How to achieve this?

```js
function ontop()
{
var d=document.getElementById('a').style.backgroundImage="url(https://i.ibb.co/0DvMRj4/wcheetah.png)";
console.log(d);
}
```

```css
.boxright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48.3vh;
  left: 50.98vw;
  
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid black;
  background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/cYnc1Ky/kisspng-cave-euclidean-vector-illustration-vector-cave-5a7a360b205458-5617697615179586671324.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="boxright" id="a"></div>
<button onclick="ontop();">place another image indide cave</button>
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: position the cheeteh inside or top?

Comment: @prashant-pimpale  on buttonclick i want the cheetah to apper inside the cave

Comment: @%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%94  wanto position cheetah so that it appear inside the cave

Comment: Like, push new image inside current div?

Comment: @prashant-pimpale any thing that it should feel that the cheetah is inside the cave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on click add class to `div` that in css add [pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) with the image

```js
function ontop()
{
   document.getElementById('a').classList.add('cheeteh');
}
```

```css
.boxright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48.3vh;
  left: 50.98vw;
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 40.0vh;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid black;
  background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/cYnc1Ky/kisspng-cave-euclidean-vector-illustration-vector-cave-5a7a360b205458-5617697615179586671324.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  
  }
  .cheeteh:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/0DvMRj4/wcheetah.png);
    z-index: 4;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="boxright" id="a"></div>
<button onclick="ontop();">place another image on top</button>
```

Comment: @%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%94  psedo element works perfect... great information brother

Comment: happy to help and I am sister ;)